# Clicking a button to show associated content

Tags: jquery

I have four "Learn More" buttons, and each of them has an associated paragraph of content. Each of the paragraphs will be hidden at the start, then I want it so that when one of the buttons is clicked, the paragraph of associated content is shown. Then, if a different button is clicked, the paragraph currently shown is hidden and the paragraph of content associated with the second button clicked is shown.

I'm having trouble figuring out what the best way to accomplish this with jQuery is.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>

<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph</p>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
p {
  display: none;        
}
```

And here's a JSFiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/cYFy3/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $b = $('button.learn-more'), $p = $('p');

    $b.click(function() {
        var i = $b.index(this);
        $p.hide().eq(i).show();
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swuTP/

Comment: Okay so now I'm trying to add a fadeOut and fadeIn effect, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the fadeIn effect wait for the fadeOut effect to finish before running. I tried putting the fadeOut in the callback but it doesn't seem to do what I'm wanting: http://jsfiddle.net/92Eg6/

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="learn-more" paragraph_id="p1">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more" paragraph_id="p2">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more" paragraph_id="p3">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more" paragraph_id="p4">Learn More</button>

<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p1">First paragraph</p>
<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p2">Second paragraph</p>
<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p3">Third paragraph</p>
<p class="hide_paragraph" id="p4">Fourth paragraph</p>
```

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.learn-more').click(function(){
           $('.hide_paragraph').hide();
           $('#' + $(this).attr('paragraph_id')).show();            
     });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CwVU7/22/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***HTML CODE***

```
<div class="btn">
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
<button class="learn-more">Learn More</button>
</div>
<div class="pgf">
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph</p>
</div>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn button').on('click', function(){
        var btnindex = $(this).index();
        $('.pgf p').siblings('p').css({'display':'none'});
        $('.pgf p').eq(btnindex).css({'display':'block'});   
    });
});
```

***CSS***

```
p {
  display: none;        
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFy3/4/)**